# Ignoring duplicate indexes when selecting in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is a somewhat simple question, so pardon me if the answer is obvious. What is the best way to select data from a data frame that may or may not contain duplicate index values? For example:

```
> foo = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]], index=['a','a','b'], columns=['x','y']) 
> foo
   x  y
a  1  2
a  3  4
b  5  6
```

Normally when I do a selection I expect the value returned to me to be an integer (or a numpy.int64 to be exact). For example `foo.at['b','x']` correctly returns a value of 5. However, in the rare circumstance that the table I am reading from has a duplicate index, this does not work. For example, `foo.at['a','x']` returns an array of [1,3], which will cause issues later down the line in my code. Now I can always just pick an integer from the array, for example `foo.at['a','x'][0]`, but this approach will give an error if I try to do it with a non-array result, such as `foo.at['b','x'][0]`.

Is there a flexible, fast method that guarantees that I return an integer value every time I try to select data from a data frame? (For example, by ignoring every duplicate index value.) I can think of some ways to get around the problem I'm having. For example I could do exception handling with try and except, or I could try and clean the data frame before selecting from it, but both methods seem a little clunky to me and I was wondering if there was anything better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `head(1)` and then sub-select the col of interest:

```
In [40]:
foo.loc['a'].head(1)['x']

Out[40]:
a    1
Name: x, dtype: int64

In [39]:
foo.loc['b'].head(1)['x']

Out[39]:
x    5
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

However, so long as you're trying to assign back and are just getting a value then this be fine

This will return every col value for a single row though

A more verbose method but should be faster is to use `index.get_slice_bound`:

```
In [50]:
foo['x'].iloc[foo.index.get_slice_bound('a', side='left', kind='loc')]

Out[50]:
1

In [51]:
foo['x'].iloc[foo.index.get_slice_bound('b', side='left', kind='loc')]

Out[51]:
5
```

This returns a slice with bias to left side